# JSP include page dynamically in looping

Tags: jsp, include, jstl

I try to include page in JSP with `out.println()` inside `<% ... %>`, but it doesn't include successfully.

I must use `<% ... %>` because some restrictions such as looping. Does anybody have idea about this or another way to succeed in include pages? I point out my sample case as below.

```jsp
<%

 for (int i = 1; i < strVoCardList.length; i++) {

  String strUserID = strVoCardList[i][1];


  out.println("<jsp:include page='../include/include_Notification_Bar.jsp' >");

  out.println("<jsp:param name = 'strUserID' value = \""+strUserID+"'/>");

  out.println("<jsp:param name = 'strSubElementID' value = '"+i+3+"'/>");

  out.println("</jsp:include>");

 }

%>
```

Comment: Can you use JSTL ?  If yes, then you can use <c:forEach> tag. First, you must create scoped variable from your scripting variable. Ask us if you need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly recommend you to drop those scriptlets and JSP tags, and to use the JSTL `<c:forEach>` and `<c:import>` tags instead.

This would look like:

```jsp
<c:forEach items="${strVoCardList}" var="strVoCard" varStatus="status">
    <c:import url="../include/include_Notification_Bar.jsp">
        <c:param name="strUserID" value="${strVoCard[1]}"/>
        <c:param name="strSubElementID" value="${status.count + 3}"/>
    </c:import>
</c:forEach>
```

See also:

- [How to avoid Java Code in JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)

Comment: It works now by Taglib. However, I have the difficult to modify source code as Taglib now because it impacts a lot. After review the concept of include among <%@ include file ...>, <jsp:include page .....> and  pageContext.include(...). It solved by pageContext.include("../include/include_Notification_Bar.jsp?strUserID="+strUserID+"&strSubElementID="+(i+3));